# regex to match pattern at specific parentheses level only

Tags: python, regex

Sample Text:

```
output : { a:1, b:2, c: { a:10, k:3 }, d:10, e: { z: {a:20, q:20 }}}
           ^              ^                           ^
         level_1        level_2                      level_3
```

better representation :

```
 { 
        a:1, //level 1
        b:2,
        c: { 
            a:10, //level 2
            k:3 
        },
        d:10,
        e: { 
            z: {
                a:20, //level 3
                q:20 
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected output (The value of `a` as the key in the first level):

> a:1

Notice that there are 3 accurance of `a`. in level-1,2 and 3.

I would need a regex which only extracts the `a` if it is in first level.

Note:

- The regex will be used in a software whos backend is written in Python
- Recursion in regex does not work. (Still an regex with recursion would be appreciated, but would not be the answer of the problem here)
- the level_1 `a` can be anywhere in the whole output. hence extracting first `a` matched would not be an option here.

Thank you.

Comment: You have a dictionary...to access the first level use `output.get("a")` ?

Comment: No no no no no. You ***really*** don't want to do this with regex.

Comment: I am using a software for output analysis.. Which requires regex to extract those fields. I can not modify the software's python code at the moment.

Comment: You can use findall and iterate through results in order of your level.

Comment: This isn't possible with (non-recursive) regex.

Comment: @Aran-Fey what is not possible ?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, Do recursive regex work in python with `re` module.?

Comment: @jazz Getting the output the OP wants. @ JayJoshi No.

Comment: then.. I guess the question, practically can not be answered :( .

Comment: Answer can always be found. Just explain this, if you see the given string of data and have to manually look for matches, what will you be looking for and in which fashion, based on that we will be able to help you in mapping pattern.

Comment: Please provide a feedback on my answer.. Is it correct approach in this case.?

Answer (score 1):

This *theoretically* works for up to 3 parentheses levels.. if you have enough time and memory to allow enough backtracking. ;-)

```
import re
s = 'output : { a:1, b:2, c: { a:10, k:3 }, d:10, e: { z: {a:20, q:20 }}}'
print(re.search(r'^[^{]*\{(?:[^{]*(?:\{(?:[^{]*(?:\{[^{]*\})?)*[^{]*\})?)*[^{]*(a:\s*\d+)(?:[^{]*(?:\{(?:[^{]*(?:\{[^{]*\})?)*[^{]*\})?)*[^{]*\}[^}]*$', s).groups(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe get regex to search with specific whitespaces at the beginning?

since it's python, and you're using tabs - disregard this line, as i realize it's an output rather than a python script itself 
you could do a search for

```
^\s\sa
```

as this will search for a with 2 white spaces before it? it appears to be tabbed twice in. but if it's a single tab just use one `\s` if it's 8 spaces you could use `\s{8}`

if you're search "output : { a:1, b:2, c: { a:10, k:3 }, d:10, e: { z: {a:20, q:20 }}}"
maybe try

```
\s:\s\{\sa
```

i'm not sure what you're looking for exactly, to fully help...

Comment: the `a` can also appear at the end of the `output { }`. So it would collect level-2 or level-3 `a` if it is first in the json. (refer note-3). the only condition that we can apply is that it should be in first level only.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to collect the the field `a` in level-1 with following regex:

With recursion :

```
 ^{((?:[^{}]|{(?1)})*)a:(\d+)
```

However, recursion is not supported in Python, hence I have removed the recursion and changed so it would work till 3 nested levels.

Without recursion:

```
^{(?:(?:[^{}]|{(?:(?:[^{}]|{(?:(?:[^{}]|{(?:(?:[^{}])*)})*)})*)})*)a:(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

With ast and regex:

```
import ast,re
output="{ a:1, b:2, c: { a:10, k:3 }, d:10, e: { z: {a:20, q:20 }}}"
output=re.sub(r"\b(\w+)\b:",r"'\1':",output)
d=ast.literal_eval(output)
print(d["a"])
```